# How to get Mutlibit Hd private keys from mnemonic

Tags: private-key, bip32-hd-wallets, private-key-export, multibit-hd

I'm trying to use this tool: https://dcpos.github.io/bip39/ but none of the addresses match. I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 3):

In multibit HD clicking wallet dashboard under wallet capabilities the BIP32 derivation path was shown as m/0h but as per this post https://github.com/keepkey/multibit-hd/issues/445 the derivation path is m/0'/0 which gave me the correct addresses and private keys.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how [bitcoin-explorer](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki) piped commands yield the correct results

**Compressed Private Key m/0'/0/0 in wallet input format (WIF):**

% echo "skin join dog sponsor camera puppy ritual diagram arrow poverty boy elbow" | bx mnemonic-to-seed | bx hd-new | bx hd-private -d -i 0 | bx hd-private -i 0 | bx hd-private -i 0 | bx hd-to-ec | sed 's/$/01/' | bx base58check-encode -v 128

`Kx4ZTj7zmT75iDjiggqwPtAYfQfzuTX8627mWWEch8Ai9arpF5iU`

**Compressed Public Key M/0'/0/0:**

% echo "skin join dog sponsor camera puppy ritual diagram arrow poverty boy elbow" | bx mnemonic-to-seed | bx hd-new | bx hd-public -d -i 0 | bx hd-public -i 0 | bx hd-public -i 0 | bx hd-to-ec

`022d5f6ec82bb1ac531b9dbe48995c0b43a41dac39dcc342dd0e3cb8a77b3e4580`

**Compressed Public Address of M/0'/0/0:**

% echo "skin join dog sponsor camera puppy ritual diagram arrow poverty boy elbow" | bx mnemonic-to-seed | bx hd-new | bx hd-public -d -i 0 | bx hd-public -i 0 | bx hd-public -i 0 | bx hd-to-ec | bx ec-to-address -v 0

`12QxtuyEM8KBG3ngNRe2CZE28hFw3b1KMJ`

Answer (score 1):

Here are my notes on how to recover / rebuild / regenerate / extract the addresses and keys used by MultiBit HD:

1. Go to https://iancoleman.github.io/bip39/
2. In the field "BIP39 Mnemonic" fill in your 12 wallet generation words
3. No password
4. Coin: Bitcoin
5. Under Derivation Path, select the BIP32
   tab
6. Derivation path (copy paste this): m/0'/0
7. Your addresses are now
   displayed at the end of the page. Happiness ;)

Comment: Users should be cautious following links to websites which ask for private data, there is no reason to believe it will not steal your money at the first opportunity.

Comment: m/0'/1 for change addresses

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tarun1475/Nodejs-implementation-of-BIP39-for-multicoin-crypto-wallet

We often use Bip39 to generate Mnemonic(Human readable digest) for bitcoin and other crypto wallets.There is a need of a library which make use of BIP39 in use cases like multicoin crypto wallet and other application which are external from blockchain.I have made use of both the best libraries to implement such kind of features.